# Какова уважительная форма слова "кошка"?

Tags: лексика

Какова уважительная форма слова "кошка"?

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что в русском языке есть такое понятие как "уважительная форма" существительных?

Answer (score 4):

О котах и кошках

**Слово "кот"** известно с 10-11 вв, общеславянское основа котъ (предположительно раннее славянское заимствование из латинского языка).

**Слово "кошка"** (в письменных источниках известно с 1307 года) имело начальную форму котъка , затем кочъка (возможно, **как ласкательный вариант**, сравнить: собака – собачка). Слово "кошечий" появилось много позднее, в словарях с 1731 года.

**Суффикс К** в русском языке используется для обозначения женского пола: артист – артистка, земляк – землячка.  А вот **суффикс ШК** – разговорный, просторечный: кино – киношка, **но к "кошке" он отношения не имеет.**

(Этимологический материал взят из словаря Черных).

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla. Сам не задумывался над этим вопросом так глубоко, чтобы разобрать слово. Только, вот, последнее утверждение не кажется Вам чуточку необоснованным?  
Г-ну бехемотхусу тоже спс за внимание. Я не филолог (не этимолог, не энтомолог), но сильно разочаруюсь в языке, в котором отсутствует  такое понятие как "уважительная форма" :(

Comment: @Игорь а почему разочаруетесь? Ведь кошке можно сказать: "Слышь, животное, а ну жрать быстро!" -- и это будет грубо. А можно как-то так: "Мурка, пошли есть!" -- тогда это будет довольно ласковым обращением. *Уважительная форма* -- совершенно не свойственное русскому языку явление (свойственно ли оно вообще какому-либо другому?). Да и зачем, право, выражать уважение к корове или обезьяне, они этого даже не ощутят!

Comment: @Aer, а я, вот, ощущю. И буду теперь переживать за то животное, которое Вы так неласково, даже грубовато назвали "Муркой":)

Comment: Не переживайте так: для глубокоуважаемой кошки есть обращение Киса.

Comment: "Уважительного" суффикса  в русском языке, к сожалению, нет, поэтому нейтральная форма без дополнительной коннотации (эмоционально-оценочного дополнения  к основному значению)  – это уже неплохо. Вот собакам меньше повезло. Помните, у Булгакова: Грохот в дверь, голос: "Отворяй, собака!"  – "Кому это он"?

Answer (score 2):

В русском русском языке нет "уважительной формы" существительных.

Есть диминутив, есть пейоратив, есть аугментатив, а вот "хоноративов"/"магнификативов" - нет. К тому же неясно, с чего бы "шк" в **данном** случае относить к пейоративным суффиксам? С того, что в других словах с другим генезисом это так?!